# Get ID of user being updated inside Form Request to ignore validation when updating same user

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

When updating a specific user, I want to run `unique` validation for the 'username' and 'studentNumber' fields, but only for other users and not for the same user being updated because its already owned by them. If I use `unique:users` only, it will cause errors when updating because it will run the validation against the user themselves. Instead, I used `Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)` to ignore the user being updated, but I need to pass the id of the user being updated to the `Form Request`. How do I accomplish this?

**UserController.php**

```php
    public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, string $id)
    {
        try{
            DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->update($request->validated());
        }catch(Exception $ex){
            return response()->json(['message' => $ex->getMessage()], 409);

        }

    }
```

**UpdateUserRequest.php**

```php
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'username' => [  Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id), 'string', 'max:255'],
            'studentNumber' => [ Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id), 'string'],

        ];
    }
```

Comment: is this a route parameter or a input that contains the user id?

Comment: @lagbox its a route parameter, ```PUT /api/user/{id}```

Comment: `$userId = $this->route('id')`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just validate first and then try the update?

you can use one of this two examples:

```
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, string $id)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $request->rules());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
    }

    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    ...
```

---

```
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, string $id)
{
    $validData = $request->validated();
    // if not valid it throws error or anything you change in failedValidation() method 

    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->update($validData);
    ...
```

Comment: That would work but i have so many fields to validate against, it wouldn't be appropriate to put all these validations in the controller method.

Comment: I change the code to use your UpdateUserRequest

Comment: I appreciate your solution, but a better approach is to access the URL parameter by using ```$this```, ```Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->route('user'))``` would give you the user id being updated.